# Calculate summary stats along columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to calculate statistics (count of observations within some percentile range) in pandas DataFrame.

I have the following DataFrame

```
 Austria Japan    USA
   0.8    0.1    0.4
   0.5    0.8    0.3
   0.4    0.5    0.8
   0.1    0.1    0.7
   0.3    0.9    0.9
```

I would like to achieve the following result.

Help much appreciated

```
                Count(PERCENTILE(x<0.4))        Count(PERCENTILE(0.4<x<0.7))        Count(PERCENTILE(x>0.7))
    Austria                     
    Japan                       
    USA
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I think it should be something with Groupby operations but I get stuck since I don't know how to set the percentile ranges. Additionally I tried describe method but there the percentiles are always between 0 and the chosen upper boundary. I also don't know how to further extract the counts.

Comment: I have corrected my question. So as a result I want to count the observations within the specified percentile ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to realign your data. You'll need to groupby, as you said, and so you will need to group the data into one column first. I use [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.melt.html) for this.

Then, using [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), I will assign into a new column the `bin` in which the value belongs to, from a list of bins called `categories`. If you want to use **names** instead of the actual bins values, just uncomment the code with the `labels` part.

Then, grouping by `bins` and using [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), I can count the number of bins there are per group.

If you really want the output as you asked in the question, use [`df.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
df = pd.read_csv('some_data.csv')
df = pd.melt(df, var_name='country', value_name='value')
print(df)
#     country  value
# 0   Austria    0.8
# 1   Austria    0.5
# 2   Austria    0.4
# 3   Austria    0.1
# 4   Austria    0.3
# 5     Japan    0.1
# 6     Japan    0.8
# 7     Japan    0.5
# 8     Japan    0.1
# 9     Japan    0.9
# 10      USA    0.4
# 11      USA    0.3
# 12      USA    0.8
# 13      USA    0.7
# 14      USA    0.9

categories = [0.0, 0.4, 0.7, 1.0]
# labels = ['Count(Percentile(x<0.4))', 'Count(Percentile(0.4<x<0.7))', 'Count(Percentile(0.7<x))']
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['value'], categories)#, labels=labels)
print(df)
#     country  value        bins
# 0   Austria    0.8  (0.7, 1.0]
# 1   Austria    0.5  (0.4, 0.7]
# 2   Austria    0.4  (0.0, 0.4]
# 3   Austria    0.1  (0.0, 0.4]
# 4   Austria    0.3  (0.0, 0.4]
# 5     Japan    0.1  (0.0, 0.4]
# 6     Japan    0.8  (0.7, 1.0]
# 7     Japan    0.5  (0.4, 0.7]
# 8     Japan    0.1  (0.0, 0.4]
# 9     Japan    0.9  (0.7, 1.0]
# 10      USA    0.4  (0.0, 0.4]
# 11      USA    0.3  (0.0, 0.4]
# 12      USA    0.8  (0.7, 1.0]
# 13      USA    0.7  (0.4, 0.7]
# 14      USA    0.9  (0.7, 1.0]

df = df.groupby(['country'])['bins'].value_counts()
print(df)
# country  bins      
# Austria  (0.0, 0.4]    3
#          (0.4, 0.7]    1
#          (0.7, 1.0]    1
# Japan    (0.0, 0.4]    2
#          (0.7, 1.0]    2
#          (0.4, 0.7]    1
# USA      (0.0, 0.4]    2
#          (0.7, 1.0]    2
#          (0.4, 0.7]    1

print(df.unstack())
# bins     (0.0, 0.4]  (0.4, 0.7]  (0.7, 1.0]
# country                                    
# Austria           3           1           1
# Japan             2           1           2
# USA               2           1           2
```